# Android manifest.xml

Tags: android, tabs, android-manifest, tabview

I'm working on the Tabs example from Google Android Developers site (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) but I'm stuck in step 2.

At the very end of step 2 says "Duplicate this for each of the three activities, and add the corresponding  tags to the Android Manifest file"

What exactly do I have to add to the AndroidManifest.xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how your Manifest file should be:

```
    <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SongsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>

</application>
```

This will work for sure!!

Answer (score 4):

just add every  activity AndroidManifest.xml

```
main activity use:
<activity android:name=".Tabs">
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
another activity use:
 <activity android:name=".Tab1">
     <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I did not understand from the tutorial that I needed to add the Tabs activity as MAIN and LAUNCHER. So every time, the app installed and nothing opened. You saved me a lot of frustration, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have register each activities in AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the corresponding `<activity>` tags for each one of the three activities. The AndroidManifest.xml file describes the components of the application (amongst [other things](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) like permissions and API level support).

In this example you have to add three definitions:

```
<activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".SongsActivity"/>
```