# Click imagebutton go other class

Tags: android, imageview, imagebutton

Hello I've got an app and I need help regarding `ImageButton`.

**Code:**

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.social);

        ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(social.this,facebook.class));
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

**manifest file**

```
   android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ana"></activity>
         <activity android:name="facebook"></activity>
          <activity android:name="instagram"></activity>
           <activity android:name="pinterest"></activity>
            <activity android:name="twitter"></activity>
             <activity android:name="youtube"></activity>
              <activity android:name="social"></activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Layout file**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/fbf" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aas" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/yoube" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ss" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/mysp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:src="@drawable/sc" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tumblr" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:src="@drawable/justinlogo" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:src="@drawable/insta" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fbf" />
```

What I want to do is, when i click the ImageButton it should open `facebook` class. I made it with normal button but, unlike normal button, its not working with ImageButton.

Its giving error *"application stopped" !* someone help me ? Thanks all.

**LOGCAT REPORT **
[image]

Comment: What does `LogCat` says ?

Comment: Does `facebook.class` extends from `Activity`  ?

Comment: did you define facebook.class in your manifest.xml??

Comment: yes i added activity at manifest and im tried at my phone not on Virtual phone wait i'll try at virtual and write logcat report.thx ur answers

Comment: yes include extend activity

Comment: post your manifest and logcat...

Comment: post social layout file.

Comment: i added logcart report pls look link same error returned !

Comment: @MacSTD Post complete logcat in your question

Comment: I wrote link pls look there

Answer (score 0):

Add `dot .` prefix(**dot means your package name. It's more short type of declaration.**) in your activities in manifest file,i.e.

```
<activity android:name=".ana"></activity>
<activity android:name=".facebook"></activity>
<activity android:name=".instagram"></activity>
<activity android:name=".pinterest"></activity>
<activity android:name=".twitter"></activity>
<activity android:name=".youtube"></activity>
<activity android:name=".social"></activity>
```

And clean your project.

For more info see [How to add activity in manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450421/how-to-add-activity-in-manifest-file)

And change

```
    ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

to

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

Because in  social layout  file `ImageButton`  id is `imageButton1`

Comment: thnk you sir im trying

Comment: @MacSTD Ok,also try to clean your project.

Comment: @MacSTD Did you change your code as suggested in answer,also try to clean your project and post complete logcat exception in question because in that link the exception is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

**ITS NOT A PROPER WAY TO DEFINE CLASS IN ACTIVITY.......**..

There are some proper mathods to declare Activity Class in MANIFEST
If all class files are in **same package (main package) define classes like below..**

```
<activity android:name=".ana"></activity>
<activity android:name=".facebook"></activity>
<activity android:name=".instagram"></activity>
<activity android:name=".pinterest"></activity>
<activity android:name=".twitter"></activity>
<activity android:name=".youtube"></activity>
<activity android:name=".social"></activity>
```

**if its in another package define it with package names like**

```
<activity android:name="com.example.package2.social"></activity>
```

and one another thing that **always define CLASS WITH FIRST LETTER CAPITAL..... like Ana or Facebook or Social**

**Edit :**

There is Difference between `ImageButton` and `ImageView`..
you are calling wrong ID...

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); <-- calling imageview for imagebutton...
```

it shouldbe like this,,

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);<-- calling imagebutton...
```

Comment: i tried but neggative.when i click social button its stoping.

Comment: you were getting typecast error.. see my edited answer

Comment: Ohkk.. thats the NullPointerException........ on line number 15 of facebook.java class file..

Comment: Ow I was looking class 15 but not error on eclipse if I will write here facebook.class can u tell me what is the problem on my project ?

Comment: It's webview client line